# How to get the ID linked with the highest value in a subset of values based on a label, for every label in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

So I think this question can be visualized the best as following, given a dataframe:

```
val_1          true_val ID      label
-0.0127894447       0.0  1       A
0.9604560385        1.0  2       A
0.0001271985        0.0  3       A
0.0007419337        0.0  3       B
0.3420448566        0.0  2       B
0.1322384726        1.0  4       B
```

So what I want to get is:

```
val_1          true_val    label  ID_val_1_highest    ID_true_val_highest
0.9604560385        1.0      A        2                 2
0.3420448566        1.0      B        2                 4
```

Or even more preferable, the last 2 columns only (so just the ID's so I can calculate precision and recall)

I want to get the ID that has the highest value for both val_1 and true_val and then return both corresponding ID's for every label.

Anyone have an idea how to do this? I tried:

> df.sort_values('val_1', ascending=False).drop_duplicates(['label'])

But it doesn't return the ID associated with the highest value for label X, for both values. Note: ID can appear more than once in the 'ID' column.

Comment: can you explain last `2,2` and `5,6` ?

Comment: 2,2 = 2 in ID column, ID 2 has the highest value for val_1 as well as true_val (0.9604560385    and 1) and 5,6 is the same story, however ID 5 has the highest value for val_1, while ID 6 has the highest value for true_val. I have added column titles for more clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) with convert `ID` to index for `ID` by maximal `val1` and `true_val` columns, last add to first `DataFrame` by [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df1 = df.sort_values('true_val', ascending=False).drop_duplicates(['label'])
print (df1)
      val_1  true_val  ID label
1  0.960456       1.0   2     A
5  0.132238       1.0   6     B

df2 = df.set_index('ID').groupby('label').idxmax().add_suffix('_highest')
print (df2)
       val_1_highest  true_val_highest
label                                 
A                  2                 2
B                  5                 6

df = df1.join(df2, on='label')
print (df)
      val_1  true_val  ID label  val_1_highest  true_val_highest
1  0.960456       1.0   2     A              2                 2
5  0.132238       1.0   6     B              5                 6
```

Comment: @Manakin - seems more complicated.

Comment: Wait so if I only want to get the IDs (which Is essentially the only thing I need) I can use: df = df.set_index('ID').groupby('label').idxmax().

Does this also account to IDs that appear more than once? So for example ID = [1 2 3 2 3 4] in my original example?

Comment: @stacksonoverflow - it return only first match, can you add expcted output for new data?

Comment: yeah ive changed it, it contains now duplicate IDs

Comment: @stacksonoverflow - tested answer and working correct, returned first `ID` by first max value.

Comment: Yes so the same ID can appear multiple times in the output right for different labels? Then yes its correct, thank you! I'll just use the variation that returns the ID's for highest values since its all I need!

Comment: @stacksonoverflow - hmm, do you need only first max value?

Comment: for every label yes, but different labels can have the same ID with max value

Comment: @stacksonoverflow - OK, I think my solution working like need. If duplicated `ID` it is no problem.